# "addmm_impl_cpu_" not implemented for 'Half'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama

This is the code for authentication:

```
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
#I passed the correct token and got `Token is valid (permission: read)`
notebook_login()
```

this is the code to create a model

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
                                          use_auth_token=True,                                                                              
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
                                         device_map='auto',
                                         torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                                         use_auth_token=True,                                                                                                                                     
                                         )
```

this is the `model.config`

```
LlamaConfig {
  "_name_or_path": "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
  "architectures": [
    "LlamaForCausalLM"
  ],
  "bos_token_id": 1,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "hidden_act": "silu",
  "hidden_size": 4096,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 11008,
  "max_position_embeddings": 4096,
  "model_type": "llama",
  "num_attention_heads": 32,
  "num_hidden_layers": 32,
  "num_key_value_heads": 32,
  "pretraining_tp": 1,
  "rms_norm_eps": 1e-06,
  "rope_scaling": null,
  "tie_word_embeddings": false,
  "torch_dtype": "float16",   ----------------
  "transformers_version": "4.32.0",
  "use_cache": true,
  "vocab_size": 32000
}
```

'Half':  refers to the half-precision floating-point format, which is also known as `float16` or `torch.float16`. It's a lower-precision data type compared to the standard 32-bit float32.

"addmm_impl_cpu_": I think this indicates that there is an issue with a specific operation or computation related to matrix multiplication (addmm) on the CPU.

I used the correct `dtype` same in the `model.config`. I also tried to use different dtypes: `torch.float32`, `torch.bfloat16`, `torch.bfloat32` but error persists

## Creating HuggingFace Pipeline:

```
# text generation pipeline. we are creating text using pre-trained language model
pipe=pipeline("text-generation",
             model=model,
              # tokenization is the process of splitting text into smaller unit
             tokenizer=tokenizer,
              # data type for model inference. torch.bfloat16 is the lower precision floating point format. 
              # lower precision data types can help reduce memory usage and speed up inference
             torch_dtype=torch.float16,
              # determines the device (cpu or gpu) on which model will run
             device_map='auto',
              # if the generated text exceeds this limit, it will truncated or will be split into multiple segments to fit within the limit
             max_new_tokens=512,
              # setting it to 1 means there is no strict minimum requirement
             min_new_tokens=-1,
              # sampling strategy for generating text. 
              # it limits the choices of next token during generation to the top k most likely tokens according to the model's probabilities.
             top_k=30)

llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe,model_kwargs={'temperature':0.7})
```

## Creating a Conversation Retrieval QA Chain with memory:

```
memory=ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history',return_messages=True)

pdf_qa=ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm,
                                             retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k':6}),
                                             verbose=False, memory=memory)
```

## Error throws here:

```
 result=pdf_qa({"question":"question here"})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to quantize the model further

```
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
           model_name, 
           device_map="auto", 
           load_in_4bit=True,  
           use_auth_token=access_token)
    
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
                model_name, 
                use_fast=True, 
                use_auth_token=access_token)
```

or use BitsAndBytesConfig

```
bnb_config = transformers.BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=True,
        bnb_4bit_quant_type='nf4',
        bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=bfloat16
    )


model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    use_auth_token=hf_auth
)

model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    config=model_config,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map='auto',
    use_auth_token=hf_auth)
```